# System.UnexpectedException: cannot be cast

Tags: apex

Would you please give me some idea what this really mean ?
Am I doing something wrong ?

```
class SomeClass {
    public Location someLocation;
}

Map<String, SomeClass> someMap = new Map<String, SomeClass>();
SomeClass someClassInstace1 = new SomeClass();
someClassInstace1.someLocation = Location.newInstance( 12, 12);
someMap.put('Hello', someClassInstace1);

System.debug( someMap.values() );
```

if `someClassInstace1.someLocation` is `null` it is ok.

> System.UnexpectedException:
>   common.apex.runtime.impl.ObjectMethods$MethodImpl cannot be cast to
>   common.apex.runtime.impl.WsdlBasedApexObject$WsdlMethodEvaluator

Comment: Looks like class cast exception. Can you past code snippet where you are getting this exception.

Comment: The problem is from I do the `myMap.values()` which objects in map own a property of `System.Location` ( if the property is `null` is ok ) 

For cast exception is not from my code it seem from the apex runtime
but I really don't know root problem, it is possible the bug of apex runtime ?

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: class SomeClass {
 public Location someLocation;
}

Map<String, SomeClass> someMap = new Map<String, SomeClass>();
SomeClass someClassInstace1 = new SomeClass();
someClassInstace1.someLocation = Location.newInstance( 12, 12);
someMap.put('Hello', someClassInstace1);

System.debug( someMap.values() );